# Copy a directory recursively from Google Cloud Storage Bucket to another Google Cloud Storage Bucket using Django

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I intend to copy a whole directory with all files and directories recursively from one Google Cloud Storage Bucket to another Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

The following code works fine from local to a Google Cloud Storage Bucket :

```
import glob
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_local_directory_to_gcs(local_path, bucket, gcs_path):
    assert os.path.isdir(local_path)
    for local_file in glob.glob(local_path + '/**'):
        if not os.path.isfile(local_file):
           upload_local_directory_to_gcs(local_file, bucket, gcs_path + "/" + os.path.basename(local_file))
        else:
           remote_path = os.path.join(gcs_path, local_file[1 + len(local_path):])
           blob = bucket.blob(remote_path)
           blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)


upload_local_directory_to_gcs(local_path, bucket, BUCKET_FOLDER_DIR)
```

How can I copy a directory recursively from one bucket to another in the same project ?

Comment: first you have to know how to get all files and folders in current folder. And how to recognize if it is folder or file. And when it it file then copy it, and if it is folder then create it in new place and run `upload_local_directory_to_gcs` with new values - so code should be simiar.

Comment: What about an equavalent of the command line tool  " gsutil -m rsync -p -r gs://:Bucket1 gs://Bucket2 " ?

Comment: if you can find source code then you will see how it works - maybe it will work the same as your code. But `rsync` may suggest it uses external program/library `rsync` for this and then all work is made by `rsync` which probably work in similar way as your code.

Comment: I see, your suggestion makes sense as there is no straightforward solution when compared to gsutil, if you provide your answer as an answer below, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though `rsync` is already pointed out in the comments, let me add one more point.
If you have a large number of directories and you can increase the speed by using `-m`. This helps in parallelization. `-r` helps in recursive copying when there are folder structures, that need to be copied.

So with `rsync` you can use it this way:-

```
gsutil -m rsync -r gs://source_bucket gs://destination_bucket
```

Please refer this public doc for [reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)