# Moving files from one bucket to another in GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have written a code to move files from one bucket to another in GCS using python. The bucket has multiple subfolders and I am trying to move the Day folder only to a different bucket. Source Path: /Bucketname/projectname/XXX/Day Target Path: /Bucketname/Archive/Day
Is there a way to directly move/copy the Day folder without moving each file inside it one by one. Im trying to optimize my code which is taking long time if there are multiple Day folders. Sample code below.

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
import glob
import pandas as pd


def Archive_JSON(bucket_name, new_bucket_name, source_prefix_arch, staging_prefix_arch, **kwargs):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    today_execution_date = kwargs['ds_nodash']
    source_prefix_new = source_prefix_arch + today_execution_date + '/'
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=source_prefix_new)
    destination_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(new_bucket_name)

    for blob in blobs:
        destination_bucket.rename_blob(blob, new_name=blob.name.replace(source_prefix_arch, staging_prefix_arch))
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68011239/copy-a-directory-recursively-from-google-cloud-storage-bucket-to-another-google

Answer (score 1):

You can't move all the file of a folder to another bucket because folders don't exist in Cloud Storage. All the object are put at the bucket level and the object name is the full path of the object.

By convention, and for (poor) human readability, slash `/` are folder separator, but it's a fake!

So, you haven't other option than moving all the files with the same prefix (the "folder path"), and iterating on all of them.